# jQuery find the value of a draggable div after being dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have created a bunch of draggable divs and want to get the value contained in the div after it is being dropped.

I did fins some resources on Stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything that covers my particular case. So I used this function to create the divs for some names

```
function displayNames(names){ //names is an array that contains a list of names that was turned into draggable objects in another function
            for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
                var newDiv = $("<div class='employee_name'>")
                newDiv.html(names[i])
                $("#drag").append(newDiv)
            }
        }
```

I tried using `$(ui.draggable).find("div").val() and .attr()`as suggested in a post, but I still get undefined. Can anyone see what the problem is?

```
$("#drop").droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui){
                    var dragged_name = ?????

                }
            })
```

[CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/xamenf2u/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: So it is just $(ui.draggable).text()

Comment: glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

according to [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) it appears as though the `ui` argument in the drop function contains `ui.draggable` which is your initial draggable item as a jQuery object.

you should be able to get `ui.draggable.find('.employee_name').html()` or some such to get at the 'name' within your dragged object.

Comment: try console.log-ing `ui.draggable` and see what it contains; your dragged item should be in there

Comment: [div.employee_name.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle.ui-draggable-dragging] is what i get. I have tried printing out the results but don't seem to get anywhere

Comment: have you tried the `.html()` or `.text()` accessors?  you don't seem to be adding the name as an attribute, and val() is not appropriate for a div.

Comment: .html() gives me undefined and .text() doesn't print anything. The names are stored as <div class='employee_name'> somename </div>

Comment: well it seems like you're on the right track.  `ui.draggable` is definitely your `.employee_name` div -- it should contain the name.  can you create and link a demo showing the problem?

Comment: I included a pic of the undefined when i do console.log

Comment: please add your full code or a live demo to your question; unfortunately i can't do much with a picture of the word 'undefined'